# PHP - Not able to use array elements as hidden form value

Tags: php

I have to make a small game in PHP called "Lights Out", and I'm starting off by making a 5x5 matrix, and every element has to be a randomly chosen number between 0 and 1.

Later when I want to process my file and acces the option chosen in the radio input (on or off), I have to know in which cell the radio was indicated. I tried to add the following to my value: `[$row][$column]`, but it didn't seem to work (error Illegal offset type).

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error? I really need to know in which row and in which column the radio was indicated.

Thanks in advance!

```
    <form action="Processing.php" method="post">
    <?php   
        $matrix = array(
            array(rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1)),
            array(rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1)),
            array(rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1)),
            array(rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1)),
            array(rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1))
        );

        echo "<table border=\"1\">"; // echo matrix in a html table
        foreach ($matrix as $row) { // rows
            echo "<tr>";
            foreach ($row as $column) { // columns
                echo "<td>";
                echo $column . "<br />";
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"I_O\" value=\"O $matrix[$row][$column]\" /> O"; // off
                echo "<br />";
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"I_O\" value=\"I $matrix[$row][$column]\" /> I"; // on
                echo "</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    ?></form>
```

Comment: `$row` is an array, if you want the offset, use `foreach($matrix as $x=>$row)` where $x is the offset/index and $row is the data

Comment: thank you @iautomation, but how do I have to implement the row and column number in the hidden form value?

Comment: It looks like the answer below outlines that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `foreach` structures are giving you values only but you're using them as indexes to the array. I've chenged it slightly (without testing yet) but this should help you along:

```
<form action="Processing.php" method="post">
<?php   
    $matrix = array(
        array(rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1)),
        array(rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1)),
        array(rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1)),
        array(rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1)),
        array(rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1), rand(0,1))
    );

    echo "<table border=\"1\">"; // echo matrix in a html table
    foreach ($matrix as $rowIx => $row) { // rows
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $columnIx => $val) { // columns
            $checked = $val ? 'checked="checked" ' : '';
            echo "<td>";
            echo $val . "<br />";
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"I_O\" $checked value=\"{$rowIx},{$columnIx}\" />";
            echo "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?></form>
```

edit: made the radio buttons value be the comma separated row and column indexes into the matrix.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you this, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. When I post the value of that radio in Processing.php, I'd like to get the number of the row and of the column in which the radio was checked

Comment: I've changed that to give you "rowIx,columnIx" on the server side in Processing. you can use `list($rowIx,$columnIx) = explode(',', $_POST['I_O']);` to get the values back into separate variables.